# What are the difference between these 3 .gitignore entries?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Here are the 3

```
/some_string
some_string
some_string/
```

I believe the second one refers to a file and the third one refers to a folder, but what about the first one?

Comment: Please don't make nonsense edits to "bump" your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/some_string` will ignore a root directory named "some_string".

`some_string` will ignore anything (file or folder) anywhere in the directory structure. And of course, you can add a wildcard to that (i.e. `*`) if you want it to ignore all variations of 'some_string' - i.e. `some_string*` will ignore `some_string.html`, `some_string.css`, etc.

`some_string/` will ignore *any* directory named "some_string".

Answer (score 2):

The first one is an "absolute" path, and will only match that name directly within the repo root.

Comment: Yes, @cadegalt. Conversely the second entry will match any file named `some_string` anywhere within the repository.